# Unwanted redirect in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, laravel-routing

I have laravel installed in a directory called `march_madness`.

I've set up some of the basic controllers like `UsersController` and `SessionsController`.

For example, when I go to `domain.com/march_madness/login` it opens a login form because I have this in my `routes.php`:

```
Route::get('login', 'SessionsController@create');
```

However, for `users` I have a problem which consists i the following - when I navigate to `domain.com/march_madness/users`, instead of using the `index()` method of the user controller, it redirects to `domain.com/users` (somehow removing the `march_madness` from the URL).

This is the part of my `routes.php` that pertains to users:

```
Route::get('register', 'UsersController@create');
Route::resource('users', 'UsersController');
Route::get('memberhome', 'UsersController@area');
Route::get('users/verify/{code}', 'UsersController@verify');
```

And this is the relevant part of `UsersController.php`:

```
class UsersController extends \BaseController {

    protected $user;

    public function __construct(User $user)
    {
        $this->user = $user;
    }

    public function index()
    {
        return "test";
    }

    ...

}
```

If I replace `return "test";` with anything else (like fetching user records from the database) nothing changes, it still just redirects.

I haven't changed anything in `.htaccess` at all.

Any ideas?

Comment: have you correctly set your url in your app config?

Comment: Yes, and as I said, all the other URLs work fine, just not this one. For example /march_madness/sessions will open the index() method of the sessions controller correctly.

Comment: What type of web server do you use?

Comment: Apache, dedicated server, Linux.

Comment: just as a test, what happens if you prepend your users resource route with 'march_madness/'?

Comment: Just tried - it does the same redirect.

Comment: What's the sequence of responses when you access `domain.com/march_madness/users`? This might give a clue. Use either the network tab of your browser's debugging tools or Apache's access log.

Comment: Redirects do not usually happen in Laravel, they usually happen in Apache. What does your apache log file say when you hit the URL?

Comment: I'm sure that by default Laravel 4 has some 'filters' setup for user authentication. It could be possible that one of these filters is capturing your request and redirecting it.

Comment: "when I navigate to domain.com/march_madness/users"... How are you doing this...?? Is it through a hyperlink...?? Could you show us that part of the code...??

Answer (score 0):

This same thing happen to me once and the reason was missing **'  /  '** in the **route.php** file which ever route it is happening
for example

**Route::resource('/users', 'usercontroller');**